# How to Combine the First and Last Name fields into a new field logstash?

Tags: logstash-json

Sample Data :  {
"_id": "5c53d41e80e3f817d9cec5b0",
"index": 0,
"account_number": 1623,
"balance": 22526.72,
"firstname": "Desiree",
"lastname": "Mays",
"age": 46,
"gender": "female",
"address": "931 Metropolitan Avenue, Faxon, Oregon, 3046",
"employer": "IDEGO",
"email": "desireemays@idego.com",
"city": "Rodanthe",
"state": "Tennessee"
}

Conf File:

```
input {
file {   
        type => "json"
        path=>'path'
}}filter { json {source => "message"} mutate {add_field => { "field_name" => "%{Firstname}" "%{lastname}"}}}output {
file {
    path =>'path'
}}
```

I Keep on getting the tag _jsonparsefailure

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm if the input file is a JSON type and if the path is set appropriately? otherwise i don't see an anomaly with add_field syntax here.

Comment: Yes The file is a JSON type  and the path is set properly

Comment: I think you have to change %{Firstname} by %{firstname}